# Problem Building ROS on Debian

Tags: ros, build-from-source, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

Just got a Raspberry Pi and building ROS on it (Yes is takes an age...but works) any way I get the following error (So close yet so far):

[ 91%] Building CXX object ros_tutorials/turtlesim/CMakeFiles/turtlesim_node.dir/src/turtle.cpp.o
/root/ros-underlay/ros_tutorials/turtlesim/src/turtle.cpp: In member function âbool turtlesim::Turtle::update(double, QPainter&, const QImage&, qreal, qreal)â:
/root/ros-underlay/ros_tutorials/turtlesim/src/turtle.cpp:132: error: no matching function for call to âmax(double, qreal)â
/root/ros-underlay/ros_tutorials/turtlesim/src/turtle.cpp:162: error: no matching function for call to âmax(qreal, double)â
/root/ros-underlay/ros_tutorials/turtlesim/src/turtle.cpp:163: error: no matching function for call to âmax(qreal, double)â
make[2]: *** [ros_tutorials/turtlesim/CMakeFiles/turtlesim_node.dir/src/turtle.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ros_tutorials/turtlesim/CMakeFiles/turtlesim_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34351/problem-building-ros-on-debian/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2012-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed it - added static_cast() around the offending types...

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2012-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1